# CSS wrap content else fill remaning height

Tags: html, css

Got a problem I have been trying to figure out for a couple of hours now!
I'm working on my own website ATM, and I have 3 divs, a header(static height), main(dynamic height) & a footer(static height).
The thing is that I want my main div to always fill the remaining screen space - but if the content in the main goes beyond the the remaining screen space, it should just wrap around it.

I'm not really sure why I can't get it to work. I tried a lot of different things, like: display:table, overflow and so on - but none of it seems to give the desired effect.

I would like this done with pure css, but I seem to be a little lost - so if anybody can point me in the right direction I would be a happy champ :)

Comment: Is there an example page or a JS Fiddle.

Comment: Please rewrite your question objectively including the code involved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are saying, but try this:

css:

```
div.main{
   width: 99%;
   max-width: 99%
}
```

(The reason I gave it 99%, is that often 100% is a little to much.)

The max-width should make it not get to wide.

Answer (score 0):

This should solves your problem! I wrote comment in case you want to know more how it works.

Here is the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vuc5F/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
body, body * {
    border: red 1pt solid;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header, footer {
    height: 100pt;
}
section {
    width: 100%;    
    clear: both;
    border: blue 5pt solid;
}
article {
    height: 1000px;
    border: green 10pt solid;
}
footer {
    /*set it to absolute to make it stay at the bottom only;*/
    width: 100%;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>header</header>
<section>
    <article>
        article
    </article>
</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might not have been to clear, i dont want a scrollbar on my "main" (in your fiddle, #section). I want the section to go beyond the screens height, if there is more "content" then can fit on the screen.

Comment: I have updated the code, check it. BTW I am guessing what you mean only it is hard to understand what you are talking about.